# Why can excel not tell apart 2 numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to make Excel differentiate between CA14*500*0*0 and CA14*5000*0*0?

I am working on a formula but Excel is somehow not able to tell `CA14*500*0*0` from `CA14*5000*0*0`.

[image: Example]

The formula is supposed to get the 20 next to the blue marked cell.

However it is not able to differentiate between the two numbers and always takes the one above the other I assume it has something to do with `*0*0`.

My Formula is: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C10;G:o;3;FALSCH);0)`

Comment: Can you share the formula you are using?

Comment: My guess is that the asterisk's are being interpreted as wildcards.

Comment: @Joost Sure i added the formula but i dont think its the formulas error because it works on other numbers.

Comment: Please add a clear example, you say you are trying to get the result "20", but that is not on your sheet - did you mean "25"?

Comment: @SolarMike Im sorry about the Quality of the Picture but 20 is in the bottom right of the Data Sheet.

Comment: @Cedric how is that "next to the blue marked cell"? So far away from the blue marked cells I thought it was a different thing...

Comment: @SolarMike the 20 needs to go next to the blue marked cell with value 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the wildcards:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C10;"*";"~*");G:o;3;FALSCH);0)
```